# Results from the same XSLT function are not equal

Tags: xslt

I have a very trivial XSLT function:

```
<xsl:function name="str:test" as="xs:string"></xsl:function>
```

It obviously does nothing (has been trivialized to demonstrate the issue). When I run a comparison of results of the function they are not equal for some reason:

```
<xsl:if test="str:test() = str:test()">
    equal
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="not(str:test() = str:test())">
    not equal
</xsl:if>
```

It outputs `not equal` when I would expect the results to be identical.

Comment: Please post a reproducible example. Your code returns an error: `An empty sequence is not allowed as the result of function str:test()"` http://xsltransform.net/gWvjQfH

Comment: It works in my environment :) However adding `<xsl:value-of select="''" />` will probably remove the error you mentioned without resolving my question

Comment: Then you must have a non-conforming environment. Because: http://xsltransform.net/gWvjQfH/1

Comment: It is indeed a custom environment but I have not expected it to be that much different from XSLT standard. Thank you for pointing it out. I will investigate locally.

Comment: No, adding `<xsl:value-of select="''"/>` doesn't make the problem resproducible; it produces results which are the opposite of what you report.

Answer (score 1):

The = operator is defined as operating on lists, and it tests to see if the intersection of the two lists is non-empty. For comparing atomic values like strings, you should use "eq"

Comment: Din't know about it however after changing to `eq` I still get the same result

Comment: If this answer is wrong, then why would you not delete it?

Comment: I don't think this answer should be labeled 'wrong'.  Every word it says looks correct to me.  The intersection of () and () is empty, so () = () returns false.  The intersection of ("") and ("") is non-empty (it is ("")), so ""="" returns true.  And if we expect to be dealing with singleton sequences, using 'eq' is usually a good idea, if only because it will raise an error when it turns out they aren't singleton sequences.  The change to `eq` may not have helped, but without a reproducible example it's not possible to say why not.

Answer (score 0):

Using `=` in XPath 2.0 means that both sequences are tested to see if there is any item in sequence 1 that is equal to any item in sequence 2. If there is *at least one such pair*, then the comparison yields `true`.

This can have entertaining and not entirely intuitive side-effects. For example, this XPath is `true`: `(1, 2) = (2, 3)`

The side effect of this rule is that if you compare empty sequences, there is no pair of equal items, which means that `() = ()` is `false`. What you write above is essentially this comparison of empty sequences. There is no pair of equal sequence items. Hence the result is `false`.

Comment: Except that the result is `true`.

Comment: which result are you referring to?

Comment: The result referred to in the question. You said: "*What you write above is essentially this comparison of empty sequences.*" That is not true. The function is expressly directed to return a string - therefore the question is about the comparison of (empty?) strings, and your answer bears no relevance to it.

Comment: I think @dret is correct.  *Every* comparison in XPath 2.0 is a comparison of sequences.  Declaring the function as `xs:string` merely means that the sequence it returns will be a singleton containing a string.  The declaration shown returns the empty sequence, not the empty string; this tells us (a) that it's ill-typed (as you pointed out) and (b) could not have produced, in the form shown, the results described, from which we might infer (b) that OP's attempt to minimize it went one step too far.  dret manages a plausible diagnosis of the reported results even without a working example.

Comment: Also, the result reported by OP is not `true` but `not equal`.